# How to use keyvault that is in another bicep module file

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I am creating a bicep files that deploys a key vault and a few storage accounts. But these resources are in different module files. I can seem to reference the key vault when I am trying to add the storage account connection string to the key vault.

**main.bicep**

```
module resourceKeyVaultModule './modules/keyvault.bicep' = {
  name: 'resourceKeyVaultModuleDeployment'
  params: {
    application: application
    location: location
    environment: environment
    severity: severity
  }
  scope: resourceGroup
}

module resourceStorageAccountModule './modules/storage.bicep' = {
  name: 'resourceStorageAccountModuleDeployment'
  params: {
    application: application
    location: location
    environment: environment
    severity: severity
    keyVault: resourceKeyVaultModule.outputs.name
  }
  scope: resourceGroup
}
```

**keyvault.bicep**

```
// == Key Vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: nameKeyVault
  location: location
  tags: {
    location: location
    environment: environment
    severity: severity
  }
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        objectId: ''
        permissions: {
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
          keys: [
            'all'
          ]
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          storage: [
            'all'
          ]
        }
        tenantId: ''
      }
    ]
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: ''
  }
}

output name string = keyVault.name
```

**storage.bicep**

```
param keyVault string

// == Storage Account
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: nameStorageAccount
  location: location
  tags: {
    location: location
    environment: environment
    severity: severity
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
  }
}

resource secretConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2022-07-01' = {
  name: 'connectionString-storageAccount'
  dependsOn: [keyVault]
  tags: {
    location: location
    environment: environment
    severity: severity
  }
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${az.environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}
```

`dependsOn: [keyVault]`
Error: The enclosing array expected an item of type "module[] | (resource | module) | resource[]", but the provided item was of type "string".bicep(BCP034)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `existing` keyword.

> To reference an existing resource that isn't deployed in your current Bicep file, declare the resource with the existing keyword. Use the existing keyword when you're deploying a resource that needs to get a value from an existing resource. You access the existing resource's properties through its symbolic name.
>
> The resource isn't redeployed when referenced with the existing keyword.

Source: [Existing resources in Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource)